# Initialising a variable 2-D array with a specific value

Tags: c++, c, arrays, multidimensional-array, array-initialization

I know that we can initialize a 2-D array with 0 by writing

```
a[value_1][value_2] = {0};
```

and if we write

```
a[value_1][value_2] = {number other than 0};
```

the first element get initialized by the number given in { } and rest all by 0.

But, the thing bugging me is that how can we initialize an array whose parameters value_1 and value_2 have been taken input from the user as it shows the error that variable sized object may not be initialized.

Also, it will be helpful if you can also tell the same about multidimensional array(instead of just 2 dimensional array).

Comment: Are you specifically talking about C, or could you use a C++'s std::vector instead?

Comment: you'd have to be more specific on what you want: C and C++ differ in that point. C, since C99, allows the `value_1` etc to be dynamic (look it up under "VLA"), C++ doesn't but has other constructs for it.

Comment: I was talking about c as well as c++ but by the use of a method which does not increase the time of execution of the program.
Well i don't know about std::vector but if it will increase the execution time of the program then what will be the difference between initializing it by for loop method.

Comment: @JensGustedt Can you tell me how to do it in c and c++ both?

Answer (score 0):

To do this in C99 (compile with `gcc -std=c99`):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main ()
{
  int value_1, value_2;
  scanf("%d %d", &value_1, &value_2);

  int a[value_1][value_2];

  // initialize
  for (int i=0; i<value_1; i++)
    for (int j=0; j<value_1; j++)
      a[i][j] = 0;
  // or
  memset(a, 0, value_1*value_2*sizeof(int));

  return 0;
}
```

In C++, variable length arrays are not supported, as @JensGustedt pointed out. On the other hand, `g++` supports it, so the same code above will work there too.

As far as I know, initializers in variable sized objects are not supported, either in C or in C++.

Comment: Does the two methods of initializing take up same time?

Comment: That depends on how good at optimization your compiler is.  I'd use the `memset` call if efficiency was more important than clarity of code.

Comment: There is no need for `value_1*value_2*sizeof(int)`; `sizeof a` suffices.

Answer (score -1):

You cannot initialize the array using values input by the user. C does not allow this.

Refer to [Dennis Ritchie](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/0131101633).

One way to achieve the same thing can be done by using the `malloc()` function.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<malloc.h>

int main(void)
{
    int limit;
    printf("Enter the array limit:- ");
    scanf("%d",&limit);
    int *arr = (int*)malloc(sizeof(int) * limit);

    // The above statement allocates the memory equivalent to 3 integers

    // Now considering your limit is 3 and initializing values

    arr[0] = 43;
    arr[1] = 65;
    scanf("%d",&arr[2]);    // All of these work perfectly fine.

    return 0;
}
```

I hope this helps. Same way you can create multi-dimensional arrays as well. There is no explicit way to define the limit in standard C.
You cannot do `int arr[limit];`

Comment: C has supported variable-length arrays since 1999. Please do not refer to books from 1978 for current information.

Comment: but what if someone does not use the C99 compiling standard ?

Comment: The OP specifically indicates they are getting an error message that a variable-sized object may not be initialized. This indicates that their compiler does support variable-length arrays but does not support initializing them (as the C standard does not). So we know they are using a compiler with support for modern variable-length arrays and a 35-year-old reference is inappropriate. If somebody wishes to ask a question about historical C, they can indicate that explicitly.